# MPDF crashes on mkdir for its cache directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, mpdf

I use Mpdf via composer ("mpdf/mpdf": "~8.1") and I regularly have an error related to the creation (sometimes the deletion) of a Cache directory because having many PDF files to create, the processor launches several concurrent processes. It seems that the Cache directory being unique for all processes, it regularly happens that the directory has just been created by a process A and that another process also tries to create it.
What solution can we find to avoid this problem?
Shouldn't the cache directory be private to each process, for example by giving a name based on a random string?

Here is the stack of the error received:

```
ERROR:  ErrorException: mkdir(): File exists in /var/app/current/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php:49 Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: log_error(2, 'mkdir(): File e...', '/var/app/curren...', 49)
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php(49): mkdir('/var/app/curren...')
#2 /var/app/current/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php(35): Mpdf\Cache->createDirectory('/var/app/curren...')
#3 /var/app/current/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php(20): Mpdf\Cache->createBasePath('/var/app/curren...')
#4 /var/app/current/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/ServiceFactory.php(67): Mpdf\Cache->__construct('/var/app/curren...', 3600)
#5 /var/app/current/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1083): Mpdf\ServiceFactory->getServices(Object(Mpdf\Mpdf), Object(Psr\Log\NullLogger), Array, Object(Mpdf\Language\LanguageToFont), Object(Mpdf\Language\ScriptToLanguage), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#6 /var/app/current/src/docs/pdfRelevePP.php(109): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct(Array)
#7 /var/app/current/src/index.php(361): makePdfRelevePP(Array) #8 {main}
```

And the code that causes it:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( [ 
        'debug' => true,
        'allow_output_buffering' => true ] );  // <-- ERROR
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';
$mpdf->setFooter( '{PAGENO} de {nbpg}' );
$mpdf->WriteHTML( $html );
$pdf_gen = $mpdf->Output( '', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::STRING_RETURN );
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This certainly seems like a race condition. But once the cache directory is created, it should cease to be a problem, no? In any case, can you please report this in the mPDF's issue tracker?

Comment: "But once the cache directory is created, it should cease to be a problem, no?" : It seems not because the competition of the processes makes that two processes started almost simultaneously can notice the absence of the directory. The faster one creates it and the second one encounters an error because it tries to create an existing directory. The same applies to deletion.